# Angular ui-router: change content of named view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm writing an SPA with AngularJS and Ui-Router so I have this situation,this is the snippet of my router:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('profile',{
    views: {
      'filters': {
        templateUrl: 'report-filters.html',
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for filters view ... }
      },
      'tabledata': {
        templateUrl: 'report-table.html',
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for tabledata view ... }
      },
      'graph': {
        templateUrl: 'report-graph.html',
        controller: function($scope){ ... controller stuff just for graph view ... }
      }
    }
  })
```

As you can see, I have a state "profile" so each view in ***views*** can set up its own templates (template, templateUrl, templateProvider), controllers (controller, controllerProvider).

This is the doc: 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Now, I want to change the content of named view...for example I have a button in "filters" view so when I click on it I want to change the content in "filters" view and viceversa that is I can restore the contents of filters.

I have this situation in every named view so this behavior is repeated for each named view.

Is there a way to do it? Or is there a way to load a view at runtime? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "change the contents" in filter, you mean change the entire page, show elements conditionally, or sth else ... ?

Comment: I'd like change the entire content of filters. I'd like is to be able to do something like: load("view.name", { template: ..., controller ... }). Do you have advices for another solution?

Comment: i would recommend using directives and showing them conditionally ... since you can't change the templateUrl on runtime coz states are defined on config phase ...